# Excited + to (now or future meaning)

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I want to reduce these two sentences into one sentence.

I was excited + because ı was going to see her.

1-I was excited to see her.

2-I was excited about seeing her.

And ı have onether question . Does the first sentence have future meaning as I tried to do or ıt has only present meaning?

Answer (score 0):

### Either sentence will work

Both sentences express the same meaning equally well. Sentence #1 uses a prepositional phrase while sentence #2 uses a gerund.

> I was excited

This is in the past tense. You were excited but now, in the present, you are not.

Comment: The question is whether my seeing her takes place in the future or took place in the past.

Comment: @user178 It's a 2-part question about which of the two sentences correctly combines the two thoughts into one. There is also an added question about the first sentence expressing future meaning. I address this by saying that it is in the past tense, not future/present. I believe I have addressed the questions but if you see a way I can improve the clarity of the answer, let me know!